# How to force Visual Studio to apply HTML comments instead of Razor ones in an .cshtml page?

Tags: html, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017

I highlight a piece of html code in an .cshtml page, like `<div id="locationField">`.

In Visual Studio, I click on the `Edit/Advanced/Comment Selection` menu.  Visual Studio applies `@*<div id="locationField">*@` comment instead of `<!--<div id="locationField">-->`

How do I force Visual Studio to apply HTML comments?

Comment: You can't. Its added a `@*...*@` because its c# razor code, not html code. (and if you inspect the html that it generates you will see that nothing is rendered). Its not clear why you would want to render `<!--<div id="locationField">-->` in a view, but if you do then you need to create it manually (by surrounding the element with `<!--` and `-->`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'd like it because my page is 99% html and like 2 lines of razor.  I'd rather have html comments particularly while I am developing.